# MySql Update Error Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to Update a table in mysql and this is the code:

```
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE PbnNumberPlayer SET jointime=?, unique=? WHERE server=?");
            ps.setInt(1, jointime);
            ps.setInt(2, unique);
            ps.setString(3, name);

            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
```

The error that I got is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unique=0 WHERE server='pbns4'' at line 1
```

Comment: We would need to see the entire code block to determine where the issue is. For example, there is no way of understanding what values `jointime`, `unique` or `name` have at the moment. Please post the entire section of code.

Comment: Maybe try `ps.executeQuery();` instead of `ps.executeUpdate();` as well.

Comment: ps.executeUpdate(); is what you want to use. Check the contents of the  **name** variable. It looks like you have a problem there. As a matter of fact, check the contents of all your variables. Make sure they contain what you might expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put backticks in query cause **unique** is reserved keywork in mysql

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE PbnNumberPlayer SET `jointime`=?, `unique`=? WHERE `server`=?");
```

read here for more reference [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! +1
Weird thing is, my other code is working perfectly without those. But now, im gonna add them just in case.